How to solve Frama-clang installation error in dune?
I am trying to install frama-clang on Ubuntu 22.04. I have frama-c v28.1 installed and working, and all the dependencies, camlp5v8.02.01, clang v14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1, opam v4.13.1, and cmake v3.22.1.
When I install with opam install frama-clang, I get the following error:
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install frama-clang 0.0.15

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
⬇ retrieved frama-clang.0.0.15  (cached)
Processing  2/3: [frama-clang: dune build]Killed

When I install from source, I get a very long error:
~/frama-clang-0.0.15$ make
Internal error, please report upstream including the contents of _build/log.
Description:
  ("Local.relative: received absolute path", { t = "."; path = "/sframa-c" })
Raised at Stdune__Code_error.raise in file
  "otherlibs/stdune/src/code_error.ml", line 10, characters 30-62
Called from Stdune__Path.Local_gen.relative in file
  "otherlibs/stdune/src/path.ml", line 130, characters 6-118
Called from Stdune__Path.Local_gen.of_string in file
  "otherlibs/stdune/src/path.ml" (inlined), line 193, characters 20-53
Called from Dune_rules__Findlib.Loader.lookup.(fun) in file
  "src/dune_rules/findlib.ml", line 367, characters 19-71
Called from Fiber__Scheduler.exec in file "vendor/fiber/src/scheduler.ml",
  line 76, characters 8-11
-> required by
   ("findlib-loader",
   ({ stdlib_dir = External "/usr/lib/ocaml"
    ; paths = [ External "/usr/lib" ]
    ; builtins =
        map
          { "bigarray" :
              { name = Some "bigarray"
              ; vars =
                  map
                    { "archive" :
                        { set_rules =
                            [ { var = "archive"
                              ; predicates = [ Pos "byte" ]
                              ; action = Set
                              ; value = "bigarray.cma"
...more lines...
    ; ext_lib = ".a"
    },
   "/sframa-c"))
-> required by ("stanzas-to-entries", "default")
-> required by ("symlinked_entries", ("default", "frama-clang"))
-> required by ("Rule.make", ())
-> required by ("execute-rule", { id = 1046; info = Internal })
-> required by ("<unnamed>", ())
-> required by ("build-file", In_build_dir "default/frama-clang.install")
-> required by ("<unnamed>", ())
-> required by
   ("build-alias", { dir = In_build_dir "default"; name = "install" })
-> required by ("toplevel", ())

I must not crash.  Uncertainty is the mind-killer. Exceptions are the
little-death that brings total obliteration.  I will fully express my cases. 
Execution will pass over me and through me.  And when it has gone past, I
will unwind the stack along its path.  Where the cases are handled there will
be nothing.  Only I will remain.
make: *** [Makefile:41: build] Error 1



I have tried make clean, and expected a more informative error on which dependency was missing.
Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix it? Thank you for your time.

this backtrace looks like an internal error in dune, the OCaml build tool that is used by Frama-C (and Frama-Clang). As suggested by the error message, you might want to report a bug (including the content of _build/log) there https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues

As Virgile mentioned, the issue seems to be with Dune, which is used by Frama-Clang. But you didn't mention the version of Dune you are using (dune --version). Also, the error message includes /sframa-c, an odd string, as if you had this path manually set somewhere. It's not at all clear where it comes from, but it seems likely to be causing the error. You should probably provide some information concerning it.

I am using dune v3.15.2. I tried to remove and then install dune and frama-c, and the _build/log doesn't give much:
# dune build @install
# OCAMLPARAM: unset
# Shared cache: disabled
# Shared cache location: /home/l/.cache/dune/db
# Workspace root: /home/l/frama-clang-0.0.15
# Auto-detected concurrency: 2
# Dune context:
#  { name = "default"
#  ; kind = "default"
#  ; profile = Dev
#  ; merlin = true
#  ; fdo_target_exe = None
#  ; build_dir = In_build_dir "default"
#  ; instrument_with = []
#  }
$ /home/l/.opam/4.14.1/bin/ocamlc.opt -config > /tmp/dune_f8730c_output


In your question you mentioned opam v4.13.1, but your log contains .opam/4.14.1. Is it a typo or do you have multiple versions of OCaml installed (opam switches)?

I've tried both to see if one version worked better. No luck yet, so I will uninstall and reinstall opam to see if that helps. Thanks to everyone for your ideas.
